# Incorporating "Fiber Cord Wrist Launcher"

Tags: star-wars-edge-of-the-empire, star-wars-age-of-rebellion, star-wars-force-and-destiny

During a campaign, I randomly found a "Fiber Cord Wrist Launcher".  That, in theory, is awesome.  It is a major tool used by Boba Fett (and I think Jango) and has a lot of uses.  It has a grapple, can tie up enemies to subdue them, and (as it is on my wrist) is probably easy to conceal.

However, I've been unable to find this in any of the books I have available and the GM was unaware as to how to incorporate it.  Suspecting it could be in the "No Disintegrations" book which none of us had I purchased that and did not see it there either. If it is in an official book, my google-fu has failed me.

While my GM's word will decide how to proceed, I am curious how you think I should incorporate this item.  Right now my best guess is to treat it as a "Under Barrel Grapple Launcher" with reduced encumbrance from the Special Modifications book but that would not allow it to ensnare targets as Fett did to Luke.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your suspicions are correct. In No Disintegrations, page 45 there is an encumbrance 2 weapon call Grapnel-Harpoon Launcher, with Ensnare 3 Quality. However, this weapon is not mounted on your arms or armor (as Boba or Jango Fett)

This weapon has 0 Hard Points (HP), so per RAW is not possible to make it as a Wrist-mounted with the Hands-Free Weapon Mount attachment, described in Dangerous Covenant page 53. However, it's a cool Idea and your GM might allow it.

Finally, A more complex option to increase the HP of the weapon is building one using Special Modification rules. With enough advantages, you might grant the required HP.

Comment: That "Grapnel harpoon launcher" is perfect.  Thank you.  I didn't catch that.  Glad I got the book.  I apparently already have the wrist launcher already (found it in loot) but needed rules to learn how to play with it (not craft it).  I do not have dangerous covenants unfortunately.  Hopefully a friend or the local store will.  Any 10,000 ft view on what wrist mounting vs wielding does?

Comment: Actually wait... does dangerous covenants have rules to mount a weapon on a weapon or a weapon on wrist/armor? "weapon mount" is a little vague as to "mounting weapon" or "mounting on a weapon"

Comment: Hi J M. Actually, there are 2 attachments (and I only use one in my answer).  The one I mentioned is the Merr-Sonn VX Hands-Free Weapon System, which is an armor attachment, and use HP from the weapon and the armor. The other is the Corellian Arms Model 2 Wrist Mount, which is a weapon attachment and use 2HP from the weapon. I hope this helps

Comment: Looking back, I should mention that I chose the expensive attachment (and the one that requires HP on the weapon and armor), only because requires 1 HP on the weapon (and not 2HP as the wrist-mounted). Your GM might forgive 1HP, but 2HP is possible stretching too much.

Comment: I dont have to worry about HP right? Im not trying to make one. I already have it. It just comes down to the mechanics for the gun from ND (plus any extras the mounting adds if any). (It'll be GMs call obviously but eventually id prefer to know how to make such calls)

Comment: You're absolutely right. You already have the gadget. I was wondering if it's possible to build it with the available rules, in case your GM does not agree with the idea.

Comment: FYI, we followed your advice.  I'm yet find a use for ensnare (doesn't stop them from shooting me so why does it matter) but grappling onto buildings or between floors has been awesome.  Thanks. Now I just need to craft an arkham city cape and batarangs (joke).